# How can i get code safety on dart-flutter

Tags: flutter, security, dart, code-security

currently i am building app and how can I provide the security of code which typed in Dart Language? Also how can I block decompile my code and blocking accesing my code in Database?

Comment: Please specify what kind of security you're interested in.

"Blocking" decompilation is, I believe, theoretically impossible (without controlling the target hardware). The act of making decompilation harder is called obfuscation - there's already many Stackoverflow threads and other articles about it.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter code compiles to native ARM code which is very hard to reverse engineer, It means your flutter app is more secure that native apps build using Java and all other hybrid apps which uses JavaScript.